# Security Group not working for all instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, tcp, port, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I have 3 instances using the same security group, both are on the same VPC as well. Same image, same applications installed, same ports opened, same route table. The only difference is that each one has its own subnet.
I'm trying a curl command on port 5001, but it only works in the first machine, the one who is on the subnet 10.0.0.0/24. The other two are on 10.0.1.0/24 and 10.0.2.0/24, they don't work at all.
Is this something related to the route tables? Cause also if I ssh into the 10.0.0.6 machine and try to telnet the 10.0.1.6 or 10.0.2.6, they don't respond either.

(BTW: This open port 5001 is setted on the SG to be specific for another public IP request, the one I'm using to curl those 3 above).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open port's which will you need to access From the Security group, check and review it. if all is good this might be a route table issue you forgot the associate subnet in the route table. there also might be cursed if you launched the other two instance in a private subnet